# How to devide post into more than one page using <!––nextpage––>?

Tags: pagination

I want to divide a post into multiple pages using `<!--nextpage-->`.

Please guide me through this and also I want some customization in that.

You can check here what type of pagination I want to do
[image]

If it can be possible to divide post into multiple pages alphabetically then it will be great.

My website is [here](http://career.guru99.com).

Comment: Use the tag several times?.. Not sure what you mean by "alphabetically" in this context.

Comment: alphabetically means instead of using pagination in 1 2 3 4
i want to use a b c d ef

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `wp_link_pages()`. Default usage below:

```
wp_link_pages( 
    array(
        'before'           => '<p>' . __('Pages:'),
        'after'            => '</p>',
        'link_before'      => '',
        'link_after'       => '',
        'next_or_number'   => 'number',
        'nextpagelink'     => __('Next page'),
        'previouspagelink' => __('Previous page'),
        'pagelink'         => '%',
        'echo'             => 1
    )
)
```

You can read the documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages